# Inserting value to pandas DataFrame to specific cell without deleting other values in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame df with roughly this format:

| alpha | result |
| --- | --- |
| 0.5 | NaN |
| 1 | 0.89 |
| 1.5 | NaN |

I want to insert a new value where alpha == 0.5 in the result-column. When I try that, however, the existing values in that column are deleted.

To insert the value, I tried this code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(file, engine="openpyxl")
df_index = df.index[df['alpha_loss'] == 0.5]
df.loc[df_index, 'result'] = 0.2
```

I've also tried replacing the last line with this:
`df.at[df_index, 'result'] = 0.2`
but get the same result.

The DataFrame I was expecting is:

| alpha | result |
| --- | --- |
| 0.5 | 0.2 |
| 1 | 0.89 |
| 1.5 | NaN |

Instead, this is the result:

| alpha | result |
| --- | --- |
| 0.5 | 0.2 |
| 1 | NaN |
| 1.5 | NaN |

What is the problem here? Why does this remove the other values in my column?
I am using pandas2.0.3 and python3.9

Edit:
It was my own fault, I mistyped the column name, but did not see it, since I was trying to write to the last column and `print(df)` only showed the last one. The actual result was something like this:

| alpha | result | result2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.5 | NaN | 0.2 |
| 1 | 0.89 | NaN |
| 1.5 | NaN | NaN |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code should work with a default range index. However, the second line is not needed. Directly use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df.loc[df['alpha_loss'] == 0.5, 'result'] = 0.2
```

Output:

```
   alpha  result
0    0.5    0.20
1    1.0    0.89
2    1.5     NaN
```

Your code might fail if you have duplicated indices in the index, while boolean indexing is independent of the index.

Comment: Thank you, I changed it. Unfortunately, that still deletes the existing value in my result column.
Edit: Nevermind, I found a typo. Thank you so much!

Comment: can you provide the output of `df.to_dict('tight')` as [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77195243/edit) to your question?

Comment: I've found a typo in the column name I was trying to write to, sorry.
This is my first post on here, so I don't know what's custom. Should I just delete the post, since the problem did not have anything to do with the code I used?

Comment: @clusty_dusty it's up to you. At least you learned how to improve the code you were using ;)